# List of data frames with names instead of numbers?

Tags: r, list

I am not sure if this question is too basic but as I haven't found an answer despite searching google for quite some time I have to ask here..

Suppose I want to create a list out of data frames (df1 and df2), how can I use the name of the data frame as the list "index"(?) instead of numbers? I.e., how do I get [[df1]] instead of [[1]] and [[df2]] instead of [[2]]?

```
list(structure(list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame"), structure(list(b = 1:10, a = 1:10), .Names = c("b", 
"a"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame"))
```

---

OK, entirely different way to ask this question to hopefully make things clearer ;)

I have three data frames

```
weguihl <- structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 1:3), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
raeg <- structure(list(b = 1:3, a = 1:3), .Names = c("b", "a"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
awezilf <- structure(list(a = 1:3, b = 1:3), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to create a list out of them..

```
li <- list(weguihl, raeg, awezilf)
```

But now I have the problem that - without remembering the order of the data frames - I do not know which data frame is which in the list..

```
> li
[[1]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[2]]
  b a
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[3]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

Thus I'd prefer this output

```
    > li
[[weguihl]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[raeg]]
  b a
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3

[[awezilf]]
  a b
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 3
```

How do I get there?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Your `list` in your sample data doesn't have names. You can add the names first (`names(L) <- paste0("df", seq_along(L))`) after which you can use something like `L[["df1"]]` (if your original `list` is called "L").

Comment: Yes, sorry, my question is: how do I get my list to automatically have the names of the data frames? So if my dfs are not df1, df2, etc. but df_bla, df_bl, df_blabla, how can I take these names over into the list? Hmm not sure this is clearer now..

Comment: Nope, still not clear :-) Do you mean to say that you have some `data.frame`s in your environment and you want to combine them into a `list` with the names intact as the `list` names? `mget(c("df1", "df2"))`. You can also use `ls()` to help with grouping the names together if they follow a common naming pattern.

Comment: Maybe, I'll edit the question...

Comment: @martin right, done!

Comment: Maybe you can construct the list with the names you want `li <- list('weguihl' = weguihl, 'raeg' = raeg, 'awezilf' = awezilf)`

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially achieving this with `mget` on a clean global environment.
Something like

Clean the global environment

```
rm(list = ls())
```

You data frames

```
weguihl <- structure(list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
raeg <- structure(list(b = 1:10, a = 1:10), .Names = c("b", "a"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
awezilf <- structure(list(a = 1:10, b = 1:10), .Names = c("a", "b"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Running `mget` which will return a list of data frames by default

```
li <- mget(ls(), .GlobalEnv)
li
# $awezilf
# a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# 
# $raeg
# b a
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
# 
# $weguihl
# a b
# 1 1 1
# 2 2 2
# 3 3 3
```

Comment: Hm OK, not sure this works for my real data because the dfs that I want to combine in a list are first created from various other data frames so I don't know how to "isolate" the resulting data frames as the list names.

Comment: @beetroot Well, put them directly in a list without creating intermediate objects. Or you could use a regex in `ls`.

Comment: @Roland, I was thinking regex too, but couldn't identify any common pattern in his data frames names

Comment: @DavidArenburg If all fails, they can specify each name in the regex.

Comment: @Roland, well, that will be no different than just using `names` as Ananda suggested in comments

Comment: Well, my actual advice was to avoid the issue all together by using a list from the beginning.

Comment: @Roland Yes I might need a different approach from the beginning. My data frames are actually ANOVA summaries (`XY <- as.data.frame(summary(aov(DV1 ~ IV, data=dat))[[1]]`) that I ran for a set of DVs, wasn't able to figure out how to do that in plyr or so but looks like I have to. Expected a quick and simple answer for my question ;)

Comment: @beetroot I would solve the root issue (and worry about statistical implications of your approach), but you can do `mylist <- list(); mylist$XY <- ...` easily.